# Hide iOS datepicker on mobile browser

Tags: html, ios, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a webpage where I am showing the jQuery datepicker on desktop browsers. However on iOS, the native iOS datepicker shows along with the jQuery datepicker

For consistency's sake we want to go with the jQuery datepicker throughout, but that means we'll have to hide the iOS datepicker. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is the type of the input, etc? Be more specific and show example code of the html

Comment: @poashoas it's a date input, but it consumes an angular directive which shows the jquery datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We weren't quite able to solve the problem by hiding the mobile datepicker, but we did solve the problem by hiding the jQuery datepicker when on a mobile device. We used this library to tell us what browser is being used: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Change the input to

```
type="text"
```

To prevent default OS behaviour and validate the input on server side.

Another solution might be adding to the input

```
readonly="true"
```

Comment: this doesn't really work as a solution, this is more of a workaround. Is there any way to hide the ios datepicker?

Comment: @EmbattledSwag so you prefer hacking instead of native solutions? that makes it messy and you don't know for sure how hacks work on other version of browsers on different iOS versions. It's a simple clean solution for your problem. Why does it HAVE to be a type="date"?

Comment: I've added another solution to my answer